# Buttons added programmatically in View1 shows up in View2

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

Edit after solving problem: The problem was "typically" easy to solve, but took som hours with thinking and help to figure out where i went wrong. It seemed that when i created ViewController2 i set it to subclass of ViewController and voila! If it is a subclass it will inherit everything from the "mother"class. So when i deleted the files, made new ones with the same name, but with subclass of "UIViewController" it worked!

Pictures of the problem.

[ViewController 1 and 2](http://imageupload.co.uk/files/yb4sk8p1if2xvnidk8ro.png)

[Storyboard](http://imageupload.co.uk/files/peihzou3pasp53z77z0j.png) : The upper segue is the one that is called "Test1". It is connected between the views. The second lower one is "Test2" (Which is not in use!) which is connected between "Button" and ViewController2.

I am new to Objective-C programming and have bumped in to a problem.

If you look at picture one you will see a menu with three buttons. The two buttons that are made programmatically are named "NEWBUTTON" and "NEWBUTTON2". When "NEWBUTTON" is clicked it calls a segue which creates TWO buttons for ViewController2. Problem is that "NEWBUTTON" and "NEWBUTTON2" are also displayed in ViewController2. ViewController2 is suppose to only have TWO buttons and ONE label.

As you can see from the pictures the button named "BUTTON" is not displayed in ViewController2. "BUTTON" is not created programmatically, It is created with drag and drop from the storyboard.

Example of how the two buttons in ViewController are made. AddMyButton is a function that creates a button and takes two parameters(NSString and an int). This prepareForSegue method is in the first ViewController:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Test1"])
{
    ViewController2 *vc = [[ViewController2 alloc]init];


    vc = [segue destinationViewController];
    UIButton *bt = [[UIButton alloc]init];

    [vc.view addSubview:bt = [self addMyButton:@"HAHA": 0]];
    [vc.view addSubview:bt = [self addMyButton:@"HLAAA": 50]];
    vc.laabel.text = @"HAh";

}
/*else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Test2"])
{
    ViewController2 *vc = [[ViewController2 alloc]init];


    vc = [segue destinationViewController];
    UIButton *bt = [[UIButton alloc]init];

    [vc.view addSubview:bt = [self addMyButton:@"HAHA": 0]];
    [vc.view addSubview:bt = [self addMyButton:@"HLAAA": 50]];
    vc.laabel.text = @"HAh";

}*/



}
```

Example of how the buttons in the first view are made:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *ny = [self addMyButton:@"NEWBUTTON": 100];
    [self.view addSubview:ny];
    ny = [self addMyButton:@"NEWBUTTON2": 150];
    [self.view addSubview:ny];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Example of how the button performs a segue:

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton*) sender
{
    if ([sender.titleLabel.text isEqual: @"NEWBUTTON"]) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Test1" sender:sender];
    } else if ([sender.titleLabel.text isEqual: @"NEWBUTTON2"]) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Test2" sender:sender];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"HELLO");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code hanging in the air... Post the code properly where is the braces???

Comment: Your code not making any sense. I think it is a sample project can you upload it somewhere.. in [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/)

Comment: It makes more sense now? I have explained a bit more and separated.

Comment: I checked one doubt.. The first code ie starts with if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Test1"]) {} is in secondVC?? can you post the full code of that.. I mean the entire method??

Comment: You meant the prepareForSegue method right? That is posted now!

Comment: Thank you iam trying to simulate the problem.. can you post the image of the storyboard also?

Comment: Got it! Things are a bit harder when you dont got any rep.

Comment: I wil check and get back to you soon:)

Answer (score 0):

Try it....

```
UIButton *oddBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
oddBtn.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 70, 70);
[oddBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImageName"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[oddBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[oddBtn setTag:i];
[oddBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(getCategoryDetail:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[self.View addSubview:oddBtn];
```

Hope i helped

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately Xcode wont let me use "retain"!

Comment: then use init instance of retain

Answer (score 0):

Implement this code inside viewDidLoad method

```
UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button1.frame = CGRectMake(50, 10, 70, 50);
[button1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImageName"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[button1 setTag:1];
[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button1 setTitle:@"Button1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:button1];

UIButton *button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button2.frame = CGRectMake(130, 10, 70, 50);
[button2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImageName"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[button2 setTag:2];
[button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button2 setTitle:@"Button2" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:button2];
```

It would create two buttons on your story board based application. It works same as without story board application too. i hope it helps you. Thanks

Comment: Please let me know if it is working  or not and if works then appreciate  for it.

Comment: I tried it. Now the buttons created with the code you posted are also shown in ViewController2's view, so it makes no difference. Thanks tho!

Comment: Welcome @stjeyz. If you really appreciate me then please vote up for my answer and accept it. Thanks

Comment: I dont have any rep so i can't!

Comment: Hi @stjeyz , if you are not able to vote up then you can accept my answer if it is right and helpful for you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got it..:)  Simulated your problem by creating a new project.

Check the **class of second view controller in  your storyboard**. It will be  **ViewController**. Am i right? change to **ViewController2**

Comment: It was set to ViewController2. Thanks for trying to help! I will try to start from scratch and see what happens then, must be an error someplace since you got it to work :)

Comment: Got it! You put me on track ;) The problem was that when i created the files "ViewController2.h and .m" they were subclass of ViewController. I deleted the files and created two new ones with the same name and made sure that they were subclass of UIViewController. Its always a small glitch ! :( Sorry i cant give you any rep, again thank you!